# Textfeild Comparing errors

Tags: java, jtextfield

I'm trying to checkto see whether or not a string is equal to the defualt or nothing but it keeps slipping through my check. Any ideas?
Check:

```
if( lblEnterServerIp.getText() == null|| lblEnterServerIp.getText().isEmpty() || lblEnterServerIp.getText().equals("000.000.000.000")) {
        popUp("No IP address entered");
        return;
    }else {
        ip = lblEnterServerIp.getText().split("\\:")[0];
    }
```

Seting the Textfeild:

```
ipField = new JTextField();
    ipField.setBounds(124, 201, 86, 20);
    ipField.setText("000.000.000.000");
    panel_1.add(ipField);
    ipField.setColumns(10);
```

Comment: The field is named `ipField` but you check `lblEnterServerIp`. According to the name, you are performing checks on a label instead of the text field.

Comment: That was it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The field is named ipField but you check lblEnterServerIp. According to the name, you are performing checks on a label instead of the text field"
Anwser provided by BackSlash in the comments of the anwser.